# How to compile resource files into a custom framework or static library or Mach-O file?

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, coreml, mach-o

How to compile resource files into a custom framework or static library (meaning into a Mach-O file)? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by "resource files" you mean arbitrary binary files, you can include them into any binary by creating an assembly file (e.g. `resources.S`) like so:

```
.section __RESOURCE,__file1
_symbol_file1:
.incbin "file1.zip"
.no_dead_strip _symbol_file1

.section __WHATEVER,__file2
_symbol_file2:
.incbin "file2.bin"
.no_dead_strip _symbol_file2

// etc, you get the pattern
```

If you don't have a project in which you can include this file already, then you can turn it into an iOS arm64 framework by itself like so:

```
mkdir MyResources.framework
xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch arm64 -shared -o MyResources.framework/MyResources resources.S
```